# Solidity Code giving Gas estimation failed if I increase loop count

Tags: ethereum, remix

I have some basic solidity code which is running for pre-defined loop of 1 to max 8. The gas estimation works perfectly till 4 loops more than that I get below error.

Using Ganache. And loop is pasted below

Gas estimation failed

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode", "code": -32000, "data": { "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\static\node\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n at module.exports (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\static\node\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\gas\guestimation.js:142:32)", "name": "RuntimeError" } }

[image]

Code https://github.com/sand3sh/scaffold-eth/blob/master/GeneManager.sol

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code (including the `_mixGenes()` function dependencies such as `unpackGene256()`, `unpackGene32()`, etc.), so that anyone can debug it easier than retyping all your code from the screenshot into their IDE and guessing the parts that cannot be seen in your screenshot.

Comment: This is the code @PetrHejda https://github.com/sand3sh/scaffold-eth/blob/master/GeneManager.sol